# How to combine fields in OrientDB SQL SELECT statement

Tags: orientdb

I have this rather complicated query

```
SELECT FROM (
  SELECT EXPAND(INV()) FROM (
    SELECT FROM (
      SELECT EXPAND(OUTE('Streamed')) FROM (
        SELECT EXPAND(OUT('Follows')) FROM #12:3923
      )
    )
  )
)
```

which can be described as:

From the @rid #12:3923 which is a User class, find the Users that he follows and see which Post (vertex) they have Streamed (edge).

Now with this, I would also like to have the username (User.username) from the person that Streamed each Post in the same row if possible.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `unionall()` function. http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Functions.html#unionall

Comment: I did see that before my post but what exactly is the first and second dataset? How to use it in this query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

in reference to this small example, your goal would be derived starting from the vertex 'Alessandro' the people who follow him [Luigi, Gabriele] who have streamed
some post [in this case post1, post2]. is it correct?

**EDIT**
Try this query (presented here over several lines for readability):

```
select username, myPost.name as postBody, myPost.postdate as postDate 
from (select username,out("Streamed") as myPost
      from (select EXPAND(OUT('Follows'))
            from #12:0)
      unwind myPost)
```

The command 'unwind' serves to separate each line of the various posts so as to obtain a view of the most similar to a table. (Adjust this according to your needs).

The result of the query is:
[image]

**EDIT_2**
Result of the query using "mypost.*"
[image]

Comment: Yes correct, and I am looking for an output in the form:

username,postbody,postdate like doing an sql select username,postDate from users,posts where user.userid=post.streamerid. so effectively to combine a select from two tables.

Comment: great answer. any way to get all the fields from myPost with their original name? myPost.* produces myPostbody (looks like a bug) for example and there are way too many fields to specify. if i do select username,expand(myPost) I get only the post's fields and no username

Comment: Hi arisalexis,
The command 'Expand' can't be used with other fields
As for the part of "myPost. *", it is exactly the right method to get all the fields myPost.
I tried to do it myself and with version 2.1.9 seems to work properly. (see image above in the EDIT2).

Comment: yes it works like that but I would like to get the column name as "body" instead of "myPostbody" because I give the output to a (custom) ORM.

Comment: If you have several different fields of vertices, I think you must use the alias.

Answer (score 0):

The datasets are the ones that you need to combine. In your case, first will be User.username and second will be Post.

```
select expand($all) let
$a = (//your query for fetching User.username),
$b = (//your query for fetching Post),
$all = unionall($a, $b)
```

EDIT::

Well, as an alternative you can try something like this:

```
select username, postName from (TRAVERSE out() from #12:3923 WHILE $depth <= 2)
```

This will however not give you exactly what you expected. The result will be two columns namely username(from your User vertex) and postName(from your Post vertex).

With the `username`(s) that you get for the users followed by given @rid, you will get all the corresponding Post vertices of those users in subsequent rows. And the corresponding username column values will be empty.

I assumed, that the `Follows` edge is from User to User and `Streamed` edge is from User to Post.

Comment: how do you relate each post with each username? many users can stream many posts. I don't get it. What does query $a look like? I don't think you understood the problem very well